# How to edit UnrealEngine4 Build process for android?

Tags: android, build, unreal-engine4, build-error

I am having issues with copying image files during build time. I get an invalid file name error.

it seems like the image assets are replicated a few times During build time. Each iteration seems to be ***FileAsset + " " + i***. However, spaces are not allowed. is there a way I can edit the build process to make it ***FileAsset + "_" + I***?

sample log

UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): * What went wrong:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Execution failed for task ':downloader_library:packageDebugResources'.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): > file_path/notify_panel_notification_icon_bg 2.png: Error: ' ' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9,
or underscore

I have tried renaming the asset file name manually, but the files are generated during build time.

I have tried manually editing some of the java files that do the copying of the assets, but that also gets wiped out and regenerated during build time

Comment: I believe the DownloaderActivity.java is the file that does the copy process. but the DownloaderActivity.java also get overwritten